# Is it possible to use ActionLink and data-role same time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I wanted to change ActionLink like:

`@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @data-role = "button" })`

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to assign data-role into ActionLink?

Comment: When you say it does not work do you mean you are receiving an error or you are not seeing the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use data-dash attributes, right? In this case, you should use:

`@data_role = "button"`

instead of:

`@data-role = "button"`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to make.